# Losing SQL results when moving a filter outside of a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following SQL query which works fine:

```
SELECT purchase_id, rn
FROM 
(
   SELECT vrd.purchase_id, 
          af.date as affiliation_date,
          row_number() over (partition by af.customer_id order by af.date desc) as rn

   FROM v_details vrd
   LEFT OUTER JOIN affiliates af
     ON vrd.customer_id = af.customer_id AND af.date <= vrd.purchase_date

   WHERE vrd.date >= DATE'2012-12-01'
     AND purchase_id = 1122996729
) 
WHERE rn = 1
```

However, when I move the id filter out of the subquery, I get the following error:

```
ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval
01878. 00000 -  "specified field not found in datetime or interval"
*Cause:    The specified field was not found in the datetime or interval.
*Action:   Make sure that the specified field is in the datetime or interval.
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT purchase_id, rn
FROM 
(
   SELECT vrd.purchase_id, 
          af.date as affiliation_date,
          row_number() over (partition by af.customer_id order by af.date desc) as rn

   FROM v_details vrd
   LEFT OUTER JOIN affiliates af
     ON vrd.customer_id = af.customer_id AND af.date <= vrd.purchase_date

   WHERE vrd.date >= DATE'2012-12-01'
) 
WHERE rn = 1
  AND purchase_id = 1122996729
```

Some background on the problem:

Each customer can have many affiliations and each affiliation has one affiliation date (when the relationship started). Affiliations can be added or removed over time, so they have an end_date as well.

So for a given row in the purchase table, I want to know what the most recent affiliation was for each customer.

I am joining the purchases to the affiliates table in order to see the total affiliations for each customer. So for every purchase it returns a row for every affiliation they have ever had. However, based on the purchase date (vrd.purchase_date) I want to see what their most recent affiliation was. Hence the rank ordered by affiliation date (af.date).

Am I approaching this the wrong way? If not, what can I do to correct the filtering?

The reason why I want to filter outside of the subquery is because I want to turn this into a view that can then be uploaded into a BI tool. However, when I create it as a view and try to query it with a where clause (regardless of its datatype), I get the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Alias name for the subquery

```
SELECT purchase_id, rn
FROM 
(
   SELECT vrd.purchase_id, 
          af.date as affiliation_date,
          row_number() over (partition by af.customer_id order by af.date desc) as rn

   FROM v_details vrd
   LEFT OUTER JOIN affiliates af
     ON vrd.customer_id = af.customer_id AND af.date <= vrd.purchase_date

   WHERE vrd.date >= DATE'2012-12-01'
) T
WHERE rn = 1
  AND purchase_id = 1122996729
```

Comment: @freddygv, http://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/corelated-subqueries-using-aliases.php. to access columns from subquery, we need to give a name to the subquery table.